# Georeferencing automatically images

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal, grass-gis

I was wondering if there exists a way to georeference automatically an image taken from a drone knowing approximately the position of the drone.

In other words, a way to detect interesting points on the image taken by the drone, find the same points on a satellite image and make them overlap (feature extraction and matching) using Python or another open-source tool.

I've seen articles talking about SURF feature extraction trying to do it, but actually I don't know where to start. Can someone give me an advice on it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site.  Tutorial questions tend to be too *discussion-oriented* and/or *opinion-based* for our Focused question/Best answer model. While we do have [Chat], that feature has a minimum reputation requirement and doesn't see the participation volume necessary to support useful discussion.

Comment: If you are interested in ArcGIS API for Python. Check these:
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/orthomapping-guide-1/
https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/orthomapping-guide-2/

Comment: @BERA Sorry, I didn't get my mistake in my question. Can you explain me why this post is going to get closed? Just to understand how to correct the question

Comment: There are no ready made automatic drone georeferencers that I know of.  There is a commercial solution here.  Full disclosure I am the developer.  https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=linkedin_share&utm_medium=member_desktop_web

Comment: If you are asking a code question, the question has to have a reproducable code attempt in it

Comment: @BERA Ok, I got it! Anyway, I asked for an advice, I don't expect a code. I asked for an advice to understand if it is possible and the technoogies involved. If it is necessary to change the question I'll do it, but it seems fine to me.

Comment: @GBG can you give me some details on the commercial solution? I mean, the name of the software or a link? Thank you!

Comment: I agree. (This forum/admins/users are very sensitive to questions that have anything to do with coding, without code in it). If you have multiple overlapping photos you can create a ortophoto using [open drone map](https://www.opendronemap.org/)

Comment: BERA brings up a good point with the question about structure from motion software.  Have you looked at OpenDroneMap or Agisoft Metashape?  These software packages will generate a single orthomosaic from a group of overlapping images and might satisfy your need.  If your images lack overlap (or image tie points) then these softwares will fail.  If that is the case you can post 20 or 30 pictures to a download site I will process them for you.

Comment: An (older) GRASS GIS addon which uses image co-registration is `i.points.auto` - Generate ground control points for image group to be rectified (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass8/manuals/addons/i.points.auto.html).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments! I still don't know exactly how to move, but I think you gave me good ideas :) OpenDroneMap and GRASS could have some useful functionalities for me!

Comment: If the moderators want to close this, can they at least point to where such a question **should** be asked?  It is a legitimate question, and it would be nice to see answers other than "just use ArcGIS" if they exist.